# What is the right way to execute multiple AJAX requests, such that each one is inside setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, setinterval

I have a 2D array, which contains a bunch of arrays, each one of which contains a bunch of URL strings (among other data about that URL).

Let's call the arrays in the 2D array as the "*outer-arrays*", and then let's call the arrays within the "*outer-arrays*" as the "*inner-arrays*".

**I need to loop through the 2D array, and for each of the outer-arrays it contains, I need to send an AJAX request, every, say, 10 seconds (10 seconds interval is variable, different for different URLs), and this goes on forever (unless the user stops it).** If the response for the AJAX request is successful, something will happen on the UI, i.e. I'll make a change in the DOM.

**The problem is that I want to send all those AJAX requests simultaneously, i.e. at the same time, asynchronously (if I am understanding the word correctly).**

Look at the following code. It has a loop. The problem with it is that it has a loop, inside which there is a `setInterval` function called. Suppose in the first iteration of loop, `setInterval()` will start sending AJAX request every 10 seconds, but since setInterval() as well as AJAX are Asynchronous, the control will move on to the second iteration of the loop and the process goes on.

I have a feeling that the way I am doing it is not the right way. There is some confusion here. So please tell me if I am doing it correctly, or should this be done in another way?

```
for (var outerArray in big2DArray) {
  setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        method: "...",
        success: function(dataReturned, status, jqXHR) {
            alert("At this point we make some change in DOM");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, exception) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
   }, 60000);
}
```

Comment: for every iteration, it'll create setInterval and that will never end. Do you want that?

Comment: @RahulSharma Yeah, that stinks. But I am newbie and couldn't think of another way. I really wish I can do it in a less expensive way. Like proper programmers would do.

Comment: Description of the data structure is confusing; in particular "outer-arrays" (plural) is inconsistent with "2D". Are you sure you don't have an array of arrays of strings? Whatever it is, it would be a good idea to include an example in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to run the requests in parallel, I would always make sure that  the previous request is done before starting another one, as it could happen otherwise that you create more requests than the connection is able to manage. If your delay inbetween is big enough your code is totally fine, otherwise you could do this:

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));


 for (const outerArray of big2DArray) { // dont confuse for..of with for..in
  (async function() {
    while(true) {
      try {
        const result = await $.ajax({ // wait for the call to be done
          url: "...",
          method: "...",
        });
        // Work with result
     } catch(error) {
        // Handle connection errors
     }
     await delay(60000); // then wait for a slight delay before continuing
    }
   })();
 }
```

Or in case you want to run one request after another:

You either take a delayed loop like this:

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

 (async function() {
   for (const outerArray of big2DArray) { // dont confuse for..of with for..in
    try {
       const result = await $.ajax({ // wait for the call to be done
          url: "...",
          method: "...",
       });
       // Work with result
    } catch(error) {
       // Handle connection errors
    }
    await delay(60000); // then wait for a slight delay before continuing
   }
 })();
```

Or a recursive pseudo loop:

```
 (function next(index) { // entry point for recursive calls
    if(index >= outerArray.length) return;
    var outerArray = big2DArray[index];
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "...",
          method: "...",
          success: function(dataReturned, status, jqXHR) {
             alert("At this point we make some change in DOM");
             next(i + 1); // continue with the next one
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, status, exception) {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
     }, 60000);
 })(0); // start with index = 0
```

Comment: Hey I am using the second one. It has a `setTimeout()` (which executes once after an interval) inside a _pseudo loop_ which executes forever. But how is it better than a simple for loop with a `setInterval()` which executes forever

Comment: Hey can you have a look at my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704484/what-is-the-right-way-to-execute-multiple-ajax-requests-such-that-each-one-is-i?noredirect=1#comment90371544_51704484) ?

Comment: @jbel nothing executes forever here?

Comment: The function executes forever when when we keep incrementing the value of index and then passing it to the function called again

Comment: @jbel yes, but you can easily stop that.

Comment: Yes, I know but i don't need to stop it (I was just answering your question about what executes forever).  The problem with this is exactly what is being discussed in the comments in the other question: The second iteration is called _only after the AJAX response from the first one returns_ but suppose the interval for the first `outerArray` is 1 hour, and that for the second `outerArray` is 1 day, then the request for the 2nd `outerArray` is sent for the first time _at least one hour after_  the program starts running, and that for the 3rd one is -to be continued

Comment: **continued from previous comment:** ...sent _at least one day and one hour after_ the program starts running. This doesn't help in my use case, because the ultimate purpose is to monitor those URL's. So conceptually monitoring should start at the same time.

Comment: I am coming from a Java background, and I need the effect of sending the requests for each of the `outerArray`s in a separate thread, and when the response comes inside that worker thread, it manipulates the DOM, which would be like the main thread, being accessed by the worker threads to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: _"in that case your code is totally fine"_ - Looking at your reputation points on SO and your answer above, it looks like you are a successful developer. I am a newbie. So can you tell me that if you had my usecase, would you do it the way I am doing it?

Comment: @jbel I'm actually just a bored student, but yes, I know a bit of JS :) I added the version how I would do that...